# Copying a line when selection is empty does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to copy the entire line that my cursor is on does not work, it simply doesn't change the current item in my clipboard. As soon as I make a selection, it manages to copy. I haven't changed much of the configurations, I only tried some stuff and my keybindings.json looks like this:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+numpad_divide",
    "command": "macros.commentLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+c",
    "command": "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+insert",
    "command": "-editor.action.clipboardCopyAction"
}
```

Also worth mentioning is that I have tried with all the extensions disabled and the user-related keybindings.json and settings.json lines commented out. It just refuses to copy the line.

I think there could be a workaround by using the `macros` extension to create a macro to select the entire line and copy, then deselect it only when the selection is empty; however, I believe there should be a native fix for this as it is a trivial problem.

Comment: remove the `ctrl+c` keybinding it overrules the default setting to use a different command if nothing is selected

Comment: I have tried that, however it has not worked, I tried to manually add that shortcut when I noticed that it wasn't working. Issue still persists with all the extensions disabled and the custom CTRL+C keybinding deleted.

Comment: What commands are found in keybind dialog for `Ctrl+C`

Comment: [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/rxW62gH.png)

Comment: I have the same key bindings for `Ctrl+C` and for me the copy line when nothing selected works. The first binding (`Copy`) should do that. Use the key bind debugging to see what command is executed

Comment: I get 2 varying results: one:
`\ From 7 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.clipboardCopyAction, when: no when condition, source: built-in .`
`+ Invoking command editor.action.clipboardCopyAction.`
`+ Storing single modifier for possible chord ctrl.`
`+ Clearing single modifier due to other key up.`

Two:
`\ From 7 keybinding entries, matched editor.action.clipboardCopyAction, when: no when condition, source: built-in .`
`+ Invoking command editor.action.clipboardCopyAction.`
`+ Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.`

Comment: I have just realized `CTRL + X` also doesn't work to cut the line when nothing is selected as well... This is highly annoying since I almost always rely on these to code, I may switch back to Pycharm if a fix is not possible.

Comment: that means it executed the correct command `editor.action.clipboardCopyAction`, if it does not do what is expected try it in vscode-insiders, if the same behavior create an issue

Comment: The feature works correctly in Visual Code - Insiders with the same user settings. Resolved. Thanks.